# How to download files from a python program

Tags: bash, python-3.x, download

I'm trying to make a minecraft installer program in python.
currently, I've got a bash script I call with `subprocess` to download the files with wget, but that only works on linux.
is there a platform-independant python library for downloading files?
thanks,
martin

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of python library which can do that: urllib, urllib2, requests.

For instance with requests:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://www.example.com/file')
```

You may need to install requests with pip or your package manager. Using pip:

```
pip install requests
```